# How to fill a dropdown in ng-grid cell

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

Iam new to AngularJS,Can someone help me how can I display the dropdown in the ng-grid's cell.

Please help me with explanation and syntaxes.

Comment: see this one
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907373/is-it-possible-to-have-a-select-drop-down-inside-of-the-angularjs-ng-grid[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907373/is-it-possible-to-have-a-select-drop-down-inside-of-the-angularjs-ng-grid

Answer (score 0):

You need to checnge the ng-grid's cell template here is the default cell template:

```
<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text>{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</span></div>
```

You will nee to update it like this:

```
 $scope.colors = [
      {name:'black', shade:'dark'},
      {name:'white', shade:'light'},
      {name:'red', shade:'dark'},
      {name:'blue', shade:'dark'},
      {name:'yellow', shade:'light'}
    ];
$scope.gridOptions = { 
        data: 'myData',
        columnDefs: [
             {field:'name', displayName:'Name', cellTemplate}, {field:'age', displayName:'Age'}]
    };
var myCelTemp = '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text>
<select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color.name group by color.shade for color in colors">
  </select></span></div>'
```

This is an exmaple that i created via thise links

[Angular js Select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

[ng_Grid templates](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Templating)

I hope this helps

Comment: Use of myCelTemp is missing.