# Angular ng-grid editableCellTemplate throwing exception

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I am trying to set the `editableCellTemplate` ColumnDef option in a ng-grid ([documented here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/#api)).

When I do set it, even to the default value of `<input ng-class="'colt' + col.index" ng-input="COL_FIELD" />`, clicking on a cell immediately gives the error

> Error: No controller: ngModel
>       at Error ()
>       at getControllers (http://foo.com:43037/Scripts/angular.js:4232:19)
>       at nodeLinkFn (http://foo.com:43037/Scripts/angular.js:4361:35)
>       at compositeLinkFn (http://foo.com:43037/Scripts/angular.js:3969:15)
>       at compositeLinkFn (http://foo.com:43037/Scripts/angular.js:3972:13)
>       at publicLinkFn (http://foo.com:43037/Scripts/angular.js:3874:30)
>       at Object. (http://foo.com:43037/Scripts/ng-grid-2.0.7.js:2660:13)
>       at Object.applyFunction [as fn] (:778:50)
>       at Object.Scope.$digest (http://foo.com:43037/Scripts/angular.js:7896:27)
>       at Object.$delegate.**proto**.$digest (:844:31) <input ng-class="'colt' + col.index" ng-input="row.entity.Name">

If I do not set editableCellTemplate, editing cells work just fine.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'people',
    enableCellSelection: true,
    enableRowSelection: false,
    enableCellEdit: true,
    columnDefs:
    [
        { field: 'Id', displayName: 'ID', enableCellEdit: false },
        { field: 'Name', enableCellEdit: true, 
          editableCellTemplate: '<input ng-class="\'colt\' + col.index" ng-input="COL_FIELD" />' }
    ]
};
```

What is wrong?

(The problem I am actually trying to solve is [creating an event when cell edit ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647981/angularjs-and-ng-grid-auto-save-data-to-the-server-after-a-cell-was-changed), but that solution assumes that you can set a cell template)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your template for `input` needs to have an `ng-model` attribute defined as well:

```
<input ng-class="'colt' + col.index" ng-input="COL_FIELD" ng-model="COL_FIELD" />
```

this is the [default](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/master/src/templates/editableCellTemplate.html) `editableCellTemplate`.

Comment: This worked nicely, thank you. The "default" value that I got was copy-pasted from the API documentation, http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/#api, which lacks the ng-model attribute. Looks like a documentation bug to me.

Comment: Thanks! this actually works.. but I'd like to understand why I have to use both ng-model and ng-input: what is their exact meaning?

Comment: Totally agree Luke, there are lots of magical incantations for the value of editableCellTemplate.  What is 'colt'#? What is COL_FIELD?  What is ng-input?