# ngGridEventEndCellEdit cell data

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am trying to find the exact cell-data that is modified when the "ngGridEventEndCellEdit" event fires.

```
$scope.$on('ngGridEventEndCellEdit', function (event) {
    rowData = event.targetScope.row.entity;
    cellData = event.targetScope.row.???;
});
```

Reason being that the data in each ngGrid-cell (per row) contains data from several records in my db (think pivot table) and as such I would like to update only 1 db-row that relates to the specific ngGrid-cell without having to update several db-rows for each event fired.

If not I'm going to have to revert to using `cellEditableTemplate` + `ng-change` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18426060/799588)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy enough solution for what I need... combining `row.entity` with `col.field` I can get the exact cell modified.

```
$scope.$on('ngGridEventEndCellEdit', function (event) {
    cellData = event.targetScope.row.entity[event.targetScope.col.field];
});
```

However, I still needed to use `cellEditableTemplate` + `ng-change` to detect whether the contents of the cell had changed & that the user hadn't just clicked in & out without changing anything.